# CAS OAUTH with linkedin

Tags: authentication, oauth, linkedin-api, cas

I want to integrate **CAS with linkedin**. I tried by putting **api key** and **secret key** inside **applicationcontext.xml**

```
<bean id="linkedin" class="org.scribe.up.provider.impl.LinkedInProvider">
 <property name="key" value="API_KEY" />
 <property name="secret" value="SECRET_KEY" />
</bean>
```

Any other steps needed to accomplish this?

I want user to **login** using **linkedin through CAS.** But i am not able to login using linkedin.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of the OAuth support in CAS server.

It depends on the version of the CAS server you use :

- CAS server 3.5.0 : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+client+support+in+CAS+server+version+3.5.0
- CAS server >= 3.5.1 : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+client+support+in+CAS+server+version+%3E%3D+3.5.1
- CAS server 4.0.0 : https://wiki.jasig.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56164890